# Why is this wrong? Strong Cauchy criterion.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Proposition**: Suppose $(a_n)$ is a sequence such that
>
> $$|a_{n +1} - a_n| < Kr^n$$ for every $n$, then $(a_n)$ is Cauchy where $|r| < 1$ and $K > 0$

Then what follows is usually a proof by showing that the LHS is a contraction and using the triangle inequality.

I am just wondering why is that even necessarily? If the above is true for every $n$, doesn't this simply mean I can pass the limit to both sides yielding,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}|a_{n +1} - a_n| = 0.$$

Proving that it is Cauchy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because in general, the fact that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_{n+1} - a_n| = 0
$$
does not imply Cauchy. For example, consider the harmonic series, which is the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ defined by
$$
a_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n \dfrac{1}{k}.
$$
Then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_{n+1} - a_{n}| = \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n+1} = 0
$$
but $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is not Cauchy, for if it were, the harmonic series would converge.